# Call a function with multiple default value in PHP

Tags: php, function

How to call a function with multiple default value in PHP ?

I have a function like below

```
public function get( $action = 'find', $query = 'top' ) {
      //more code
}
```

What will happen if I call above function like below (with one value) ?

```
get('map') {
      //more code
}
```

Comment: Nothing, because your function contains no code. Suggestion: put `echo "action = $action, query = $query";` in your function, and try it.

Comment: What do you mean? Parameters are positional, unless you use named arguments in your function _call_.

Comment: What's unclear about this supposed behavior? What unexpected do you expect from this call?

Comment: Read the friendly manual. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález. How to use named arguments in function call ?

Comment: Look at [Example #9](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#example-163) and [named arguments](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You are using positional arguments. Passing only one argument in your function, becomes the value of first parameter i.e. $action The $query still has the value of 'top'.

Comment: Thanks @Sharjeel Ahmad. How can I pass value for second parameter `$query` ?